# Google Cloud Storage - cannot overwrite files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-storage-r

I am trying to use Google Cloud Storage (GCS) to serve static content for a website (e.g. css, js, etc.)
So I upload style.css, it serves well - then I do a small modification to style.css, upload it again - GCS still serves the original version...

I tried deleting the file. The link is still there and still serving the original version.
I uploaded it again. Still serving the original version....

Google Cloud Storage [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability) says that Objects are immutable, but you can replace objects:

> However, it is possible to replace objects that are stored in Cloud Storage, and doing so happens atomically: until the new upload completes the old version of the object is served to readers, and after the upload completes the new version of the object is served to readers. So a single replacement operation simply marks the end of one immutable object's lifetime and the beginning of a new immutable object's lifetime.

But this is obviously not working.
I am uploading files through the UI (not the CLI).

Help! I am about to get an AWS S3 to store the static contents there, defeats the purpose of using GCP!!!

MPX

Comment: Can it be cache? How long have you waited for new version? You may find some tips here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-cache

Comment: Do you have set cache control on your file? You can explicitaly set it

Comment: Thank you guys - it worked - put it as an answer and I will accept

Comment: One thing: I set the metadata and it "uncaches". But then when I overwrite the file via the UI, the metadata is gone, so I have to add it again... would this be solved using the CLI rsync?

Answer (score 4):

When you change to new version you have to remember that there is `Cache-Control metadata`. Browser will show old version until the time set in the value will pass.

It's important to remember that `cache-control` has default value 3600 second. So if not set new version of the file will be shown by the browser with delay.

Please check [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-cache) for cache-control metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage has built-in caching, per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/caching)